# Converting Old Beer Sign Fluorescent To LED - Question On Switch Wiring

Tags: circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply

I am converting a 1962 beer sign with a 9" t5 fluorescent bulb to an LED bulb.

It has power cord with an inline ballast (I believe it has an internal starter). Two wires in from 2 prong plug, three wires out to sign. One hot (120v) one neutral and one wire converted to 7 volts.This wire connects to the switch which turns on/off the bulb.

The switch is an old brass push button on/off switch. The switch has 4 wires. On each side there is one red wire and one black wire.

(1)  On the one side is the low voltage input power from the external ballast. This is the BLACK wire. On the same side the RED wire is connected to the right tombstone's black wire.

(2)  On the opposite side of the switch is a BLACK wire connected to the left tombstone's BLACK wire (low voltage when turned on). The RED wire is connected to the same tombstone's WHITE wire (I assume this is the neutral wire). This side's power is turned off/on by pushing the button switch.

I understand when installing an LED bypassing the ballast/starter you connect one end of the fixtures tombstone's wires together and hook it up to neutral. The opposite tombstone is also wired together and connected to 120v hot wire.

Usually the neutral wire bypasses the switch and just connects to the joined tombstone on one end to make the circuit. The BLACK, hot wire is connected to the switch input BLACK wire.

The switches BLACK 'output' wire is connected to the other wired together tombstone creating a circuit off/on when the button is pushed.

Question:

On this 4 wire switch what do I do with the input/output RED wires? Just cap them (I assume I cap the low voltage wire from the ballast also)?

Or is there some wiring configuration I am missing that should be used?

The reason I am asking here is I don't want to damage this inline ballast, if I hook something up wrong, in case someone in the future would want to convert it back to the original configuration. It would be virtually impossible to fine another ballast like this.

If anyone would wish to see pics of the ballast or switch let me know and if possible I will add them in a message.

Thanks to everyone in advance,

Clark

Comment: A schematic would be useful. There's a CircuitLab button on the [edit] toolbar. Drag components onto the page. Use NODE symbol for connections. R = rotate. V/H for vertical and horizontal flip. Double-click to edit. **Save and Insert** when done. No need for CircuitLab account.

Comment: A neon transformer produces ~20,000 VAC at a few mA. Individual LED lamps need ~1.2 to ~3.5 VDc at a few mA. You would **not** use the neon sign transformer or ballast top light LED's.